# WS2003 network drive gets deactivated after restart

Tags: windows-server-2003, storage-area-network, hard-drive, drive

windows server 2003 OS runs sql backups regularly and periodically i have to restart once in a while. when the restart takes place the network drive(H) becomes deactivated which i do not understand why. when this happens my quick solution right now is to right click  mycomp>manage>diskmanagement>right click on unlettered drive and choose reactivate and it comes back to life again as the H drive. the H drive is not a local drive but located on a SAN.

Comment: It sounds like you're not talking about a "network" drive at all, it sounds like you're talking about a block device being presented to the server via iSCSI or fiber Channel. Can you clarify?

Comment: newbie here......yes your correct its via iSCSI and its assigned as the H drive. what other information could i present you ? in my opinion i do not think its the iSCSI or the SAN b/c this only happens when i restart WS2003. i just wonder if it is a setting issue with the SAN ? or a simple setting i could change in this management? thank you